# OpenServer и node.js

Tags: node.js

[image: Ошибка при определении пути.]

Что делать если в проекте есть php? Как ичпользовать Openserver c node.js?

Comment: https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1030&start=710

Comment: Еще тут можно посмотреть - https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=746

Answer (score -1):

В твоем случае, у тебя наверное нет папки node_modules в **domains/landing**
Gulp не запускается, нет файлов в папке node_modules,
лечение заново запустить  установку если есть  файл package.json **domains/landing**
G

```
npm install -g 
npm install gulp
```

**node -v 
 npm -v**  какая у вас версия ? 
так как запуск команды gulp идет из ROOT

```
X:/openserver/domains/your-domain/node_modules also here

X:/openserver/domains/your-domain/gulpfile.js also here

X:/openserver/domains/your-domain/.gitignore also here
```

If you use also openserver - create your-domain as a domain

Show me you files photo in domain/site url

покажи мне скрины !